# Where to put string to search in watcher in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Kibana.

I am may be making basic mistakes here.

I am trying to search a string in log file in each 10 minutes and want to send e-mail to people regarding this.

I have tried this to created a watcher:

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "10m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        },
        "indices": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gte": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "my-logging-action": {
      "logging": {
        "text": "There are {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} documents in your index. Threshold is 10."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am missing here?

Where I can put the string I want to search? Assume I want to search a string **The system here is crashed.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `match_all` run a [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html); for example to search in the field `message`:

```
"match" : {
    "message" : "The system here is crashed."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to change the action type to mail. You need to use query and match also in that.
Go to DevTools and create a watcher. Code for that is given below.

POST /_Watcher/watch/{watch id}/

```
   {   
    "trigger": {
        "schedule": {
          "interval": "5m"
        }   
    },   
    "input": {
        "search": {
          "request": {
            "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
            "indices": [
              "*"
            ],
            "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
            "body": {
              "size": 0,
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "field_name": "The system here is crashed."
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }   },   
        "condition": {
            "compare": {
                "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
                    "gt": 1
                }
            }   
        },
        "actions": {
            "email_administrator": {
              "email": {
                "profile": "standard",
                "attachments": {
                  "attached_data": {
                    "data": {
                      "format": "json"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "priority": "high",
                "to": [
                  "destination.mail.id@mail.com"
                ],
                "subject": "Mail Subject",
                "body":"Mail Body"
            }
        }
    }
}
```